# Como remover indicador de parâmetro de um método no VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe como remover o indicador do parâmetro que está sendo passado em um método no Vs-Code, segue o print:

[Esse "v1:" e "v2:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmVQa.png)

[Método que recebe como parâmetro int v1 e int v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQmuN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Vá em Configurações
- Na barra de pesquisa, digite "editor.inlayHints.enabled"
- Mude o valor para "off"

[image: Print da tela de configuração]